# If/else statement combined with autocomplete search box using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to implement an autocomplete search box that changes its autocomplete text based on the dropdown listitem selected in Javascript. However, I can't get this autocomplete to work when using if/else statements. I've posted my code below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $("#searchTypeDD").change(function DDChange() {
                var searchType = $('#searchTypeDD').val();
                var searchData = null;
                var searchMethodName = null;
                var searchTerm = $('#searchTermEntered').val();

                if (searchType == 'movieSearch') {
                    data = { name: searchTerm };
                    searchMethodName = "GetmovieTitle";
                }
                else {
                    data = { director: searchTerm };
                    searchMethodName = "Getdirector";
                }

                $("#searchTermEntered").autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "AutoCompleteService.asmx/" + searchMethodName,
                            dataType: "jsonp",
                            data: searchData,
                            success: function (data) {
                                response(data);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    minLength: 2,
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        log("Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Are you receiving any specific error?  Also, are you using this specific autocomplete plugin? https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

If the above code is what you're using, there is a typo.  You've got `$:ajax` instead of `$.ajax` (see below)

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $(".searchTermEntered").autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response) {
          var searchType = $('.searchTypeDD').val();
          var searchData = null;
          var searchMethodName = null;
          var searchTerm = $('.searchTermEntered').val();

          if (searchType == 'movieSearch') {
              searchData = { name: searchTerm };
              searchMethodName = "GetmovieTitle";
          }
          else {
              searchData = { director: searchTerm };
              searchMethodName = "Getdirector";
          }

          $.ajax({
              url: "AutoCompleteService.asmx/" + searchMethodName,
              dataType: "jsonp",
              data: searchData,
              success: function( data ) {
                  response( data );
              }
          });
      },
      minLength: 2,
      select: function(event, ui) {
        log( "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id );
      }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:** I had a typo in my code.  It has been updated and should work for you.  The only caveat is that you're using .NET and when .NET renders the page, the ID for your dropdownlist is not going to be searchTypeDD.  ASP.NET appends a bunch of jargon to the end of the control ID to ensure that it's unique and provides a map of who its parent control is and so-on.  So, I recommend you do this for your dropdown control:

and the same for your input:

Then, the code above will work as we are selecting the control by the class name ($(.xxx) selector) instead of the ID ($(#xxx) selector).

Comment: When I put $.ajax instead of what I have it says it is expecting ":"

Comment: I'll give you a hint on getting started with jQuery and AJAX.  Always consult the documentation.  I can't tell you how many times it has caused me to hack and hack and hack and never get it to work, when in the end, I had the syntax incorrect.  Take a look at the example I posted as it was derived from the jQuery site: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Comment: I didn't complete the code, but, wanted to let you know that the way this is written, it will only use the selected value once and it will always be that value.  You need to add a trigger for the on change event for the search type drop down so that the type is updated whenever the director or movie title is selected.

Comment: Thanks Keith, I'll give this a try. Much appreciated!

Comment: I'm getting an uncaught reference error now even though I've declared the onchange in the dropdown and have it as part of the javascript function

Comment: Can you update your post with the onchange code and I can take a look at it.

Comment: I've updated my Javascript code. This is my dropdown code: <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="searchTypeDD" onchange="DDChange();">

Comment: Take a look at my answer again.  I updated it as I had a typo in it as well.  ASP.NET renders controls differently than most other rendering engines.  It appends special values to the ID, so when you're attempting to select them in jQuery, that ID doesn't exist.

Comment: So the dropdownlist control should use the class attribute instead of the ID?

Comment: You still have to include an ID in the declaration of the control, but include the CssClass so that you can select it after .NET alters your ID.

Comment: No results yet. I named the CssClass of that control the same name as the ID

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your web service as well to make sure it's hitting the method.  The format of the URL might be different.

Comment: The web service methods aren't being triggered

Comment: Then try the full URL to the web service itself.  If you have Visual Studio configured to start the current page, then open the .ASMX in VS and then start debugging.  When the browsers opens, you should see a list of the methods available in the web service.  Copy the URL that it browsed to and paste that in the web service call.  It should be something like `http://localhost:54903/AutoCompleteService.asmx`

Comment: When I launch the method from there as suggested it does pull a relevant value but how would I go about getting this to work from the child pages of the master page?

Comment: I think it's the URL in the ajax call.  Instead of using just `url: "AutoCompleteService.asmx/"`, you'll need to use `url: "http://localhost:49082/AutoCompleteService.asmx"` like I said in the previous comment.  Another thing you can do is setup just a test button on the page somewhere and in the click event (`$('.testbutton').click(function() { // make ajax call here });`) call your method in a jQuery ajax call to make sure it's the right URL.

Comment: Would it be something to do with the fact it's not a dropdown change triggered function and is just document.ready?

Comment: No, the document.ready just tells jQuery to wait until the DOM is ready.  The $.autocomplete is what tells it to fire when the input has changed.  No need to trigger anything on the dropdown change.  Just the input.  This is exactly what you're looking for: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Use-Jquery-Autocomplete-a2e3e42e/sourcecode?fileId=82602&pathId=1006708097

Comment: I think it's failing to finding the attributes by their CssClass names but I'm not sure why

Comment: Just as an update I think my ajax section is the problem as the correct methods are being hit with the if else statements.